# Expose/export class instead of module from python file

Tags: python

I'm exploring Python and how to structure code.

Consider the following project structure

```
<project root>/controllers/user_controller.py
```

This file then contains

```
class UserController:
  def index():
    # Something
```

When importing this from outside, it ends up as

```
import controllers.user_controller

controller_instance = controllers.user_controller.UserController()
```

As a Ruby developer, it feels more natural to do `controllers.UserController()` or just `UserController()` if the controllers folder was part of the load path, like in Rails.

Is there a (clean) way to omit the package name? I know I can do `from controllers.user_controller import UserController`, but I honestly don't fancy the verbosity.

I would like to have one python file per class, but I don't want a new module for each class.

Comment: Do you have quarrel with `import controllers.user_controller as ctrl`?

Comment: Yes, I don't think ctrl.UserController() reads well.

Answer (score 48):

One way to do this is just just import the modules into the parent module.  In other words imagine you have a directory structure like this:

```
mycoolmodule/
mycoolmodule/__init__.py
mycoolmodule/coolclass.py
mycoolmodule/coolutil.py
```

Code for **coolclass.py**:

```
class CoolClass:
    ...
```

Code for **coolutil.py**:

```
class CoolUtil:
    ...
```

Code for **_*init_*.py**

```
from coolclass import CoolClass
from coolutil import CoolUtil
```

Since you made them available at the package level, you can now import them directly from there.  For example, this will work:

```
from mycoolmodule import CoolClass
```

Comment: In my `__init__.py` it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coolclass'`, even though I think I did everything correctly.

Comment: Hard to say w/o seeing exactly what you are doing, but the above example should work.

Comment: I think `_init_.py` should contain `.coolclass` instead of `coolclass` and `.coolutil` instad of `coolutil` respectively. Otherwise it doesn't work properly due to circular dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

maybe you should rely on relative path, as suggested by [the above post by Ryan Widmaier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694177), but:

Code for ***init*.py**

```
from .coolclass import CoolClass
from .coolutil import CoolUtil
```